# Jquery highest nearest value in array returns undefined

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

First of all I'm aware of the multiple topics concerning this issue. But I just can't find the reason why it doesn't work in my case.

I'm trying to find the **nearest highest value** `qty` in an array. This array is dynamically created. 
So in below example the current value/quantity is `17`. I want to return from the array the object containing `qty: 60`.

Whatever I try the output is `undefined`. I just can't see why that is.

```
<div class="product" data-url="some-url-to-json" data-quantity="17">
  ....
</div>

$(function(){

 $('#form-pagecart .product').each(function(){
   var url = $(this).data('url') + '?format=json';
   var cur_qty = $(this).data('quantity')
   var highestArray= []
   $.getJSON(url, function(data){
     $.each(data.product.discounts, function(index, disc) {
       highestArray.push({ qty: parseInt(disc.quantity), price: disc.price.price_incl, price_excl: disc.price.price_excl })
    });
   });

   /* things I tried ======> */
   var output = highestArray.slice().reverse().find(({ qty }) => qty <= cur_qty);
   var nearest = highestArray.sort(function(a, b){ 
        return Math.abs(a.qty - cur_qty) - Math.abs(b.qty - cur_qty)
   })[0];
   console.log(output, nearest)
 });
```

When I console.log `highestArray` I get:

```
[
  {
    "qty": 15,
    "price": 18.1379,
    "price_excl": 14.99
  },
  {
    "qty": 60,
    "price": 16.3229,
    "price_excl": 13.49
  },
  {
    "qty": 120,
    "price": 15.1129,
    "price_excl": 12.49
  },
  {
    "qty": 240,
    "price": 14.5079,
    "price_excl": 11.99
  }
]
```

Why keeps console.log returning `undefined` then for `output` and `nearest`?

I aslo tried using a function like:

```
changePrice(highestArray, cur_qty)

function changePrice(array,num){
 var output = array.slice().reverse().find(({ qty }) => qty <= num);
 if(output){
    $('.price .price-new i').text(output['price'])
    $('.price .vat i').text(output['price_excl'])
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Things you should have tried:  `console.log(highestArray)` just before you use it,  `$.getJSON` runs asynchronously, so the `$.each(..push..)` runs *after* your `things I tried`

Comment: related: both your "what I tried" return the qty:15 entry (when highestArray isn't empty) https://jsfiddle.net/2n73urcm/ but you state you expect qty:60.  Not really clear what "highest nearest values" is for 17 giving 60 (wouldn't that be lowest higher value?)

Comment: @freedomn-m: Well you are correct. What I mean is "the next value". So when current value is 17 then the next value in the array is 60. So I want to return the object with 60. When current value is eg. 10 then the next value would be 15. But also when I have 15 as value then the next value that should return is 60

Comment: no worries - that's not really the issue, just noticed it when having a look.  Your issue is the async of `$.getJSON`

Comment: @freedomn-m: Yes that's correct, i see now. However can you help to return the next number instead of the closest number? I'll adjust question :)

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question TBH as this one is about the `undefined`

Comment: You can use `.filter` to reduce the array set first then sort and get first: `var next = highestArray.filter(({ qty }) => qty > cur_qty).sort()[0];` (probably want your extended `sort` in there)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the server has not returned the JSON you need at the moment you try to get the highest value.

Try something like this:

```
$('#form-pagecart .product').each(function(){
   var url = $(this).data('url') + '?format=json';
   var cur_qty = $(this).data('quantity')
   var highestArray= []
   $.getJSON(url, function(data){
     $.each(data.product.discounts, function(index, disc) {
       highestArray.push({ qty: parseInt(disc.quantity), price: disc.price.price_incl, price_excl: disc.price.price_excl 
     });
     // Do it inside the callback, so you can be sure that the
     // JSON is already there.
     var output = highestArray.slice().reverse().find(({ qty }) => qty <= cur_qty);
   });

});
```

Comment: Hi, this is a fine answer.  However, in this case, this question (or variants of it) gets asked at least 10 times a day (anecdotal) and there's a good answer that explains the issue in detail (there's another similar answer that also explains in detail, I always use the one above).   Rather than repeat the answer every time, we provide a link and vote-close as a duplicate.    You'll soon have enough rep to also vote close.   You might find this of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges